# How to detect where the user's click comes from

Tags: javascript, events, click, event-listener

Is there a way to know if the click from a user is from the **mouse's scroll wheel** or **trackpad button** or **trackpad hard press** instead of always assuming the user clicks with the mouse's left click?

Comment: have you tried the onwmousewheel event?

Comment: The 'onclick' event only fires with a mouse's left click , if the user right clicks , then the context menu will open , the track pad button triggers a scroll event...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Give this a try:

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

body.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 1) {
    body.innerHTML = 'click';
  }

  else if (e.which == 2) {
    body.innerHTML = 'middle click';
  }
})
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    Click Here
  </body>
</html>
```